# Failed to Compile - Expo Web - After installing UI-Kitten

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, aws-amplify, react-native-ui-kitten

After installing UI-Kitten and applying it to my App.js, I started to have this error message:

```
Failed to compile
/home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@ui-kitten/components/ui/card/card.component.js 104:20
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (104:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|         };
|         this.renderDivider = () => {
>             return (<Divider />);
|         };
|         this.renderHeader = (headerStyles) => {
```

I already looked into card.component.js and it seems to be fine. Also it doesn't look like it works with any other files other than javascript, which I think should load correctly in expo web.

Any hints on what it could possibly be?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's our fault and we're going to patch it soon. The issue exists on github

Comment: Hey, I didnt find issue on github related to this. Is it solved or under dev? Need help? :)

Comment: @PawełSmołka it's resolved in 4.3.2 and publically available

Answer (score 1):

Same here:

```
/mnt/f/WORK/React/bridge2/react-tv-client/node_modules/@ui-kitten/components/ui/input/input.component.js 105:38
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (105:38)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|         this.webEventResponder = devsupport_1.WebEventResponder.create(this);
|         this.focus = () => {
>             this.textInputRef.current?.focus();
|         };
|         this.blur = () => {
```